# C# - how to declare arrays as columns of a 2D array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to create a 2D array, with other arrays to represent the columns.

heres what i'm trying to do:

```
   public int[] item0;
   public int[] item1;
   public int[] item2;
   public int[] item3;
   public int[] item4;
   public int[] item5;
   public int[] item6;
   public int[] item7;
   public int[] item8;
   public int[] item9;

        item0 = new int[22];
        item1 = new int[22];
        item2 = new int[22];
        item3 = new int[22];
        item4 = new int[22];
        item5 = new int[22];
        item6 = new int[22];
        item7 = new int[22];
        item8 = new int[22];
        item9 = new int[22];
        itemList = new int[10,22] { 
{item0}, 
{item1}, 
{item2}, 
{item3}, 
{item4}, 
{item5}, 
{item6}, 
{item7}, 
{item8}, 
{item9} 
};
```

But I get a console error, telling me that It's not picking up the expected length.

I've looked around at a lot of old questions but they never really clarify how to define an array like this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare `itemList` as a "jagged" array:

```
var itemList = new int[][] {
    item0,
    item1,
    new int[] { 1, 2, 3 },
    new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, … },
    item4,
    item5,
    …
};
```

I've included both references to pre-existing `int[]` arrays (`item0`, `item1`, etc.) as well as in-line array instantiations (`new int[] { … }`) in the above example. Further, note that with jagged arrays, the single array items in `itemList` do not need to have the same length. This goes to show that a jagged array is not in fact two-dimensional; it is an array of arrays.

Comment: Thanks, a jagged array seems to be the answer here. However, I'm getting another problem, I'm getting a null reference console error for using  if (itemList[0][0] == 1) - how do i grab values inside of my new jagged array?

Comment: @Stephen `item[0]` is an *array* therefore it's default value is `null` until you initialize it; you are trying to index a nonexistent array `null[0]`. It's the same behavior you get when you do `var myObjectArray = new object[5];`. `myObjectArray[0]` is `null`. When an array is created, its members are initialized to the array's type default value.

Comment: @stakz well i thought i had, but its still coming up null for some reason. I've basically done item0 = new int[22] {0,0,0,0,0,0 ...}; and then done itemList = new int[10][]; followed by itemList[0] = item0; - then when i do if (itemList[0][0] == 0) I'm getting a null reference, but i defined it already as 0, or do i have to define it a second time once I've initialised it into the second array? does it revert to null?

Comment: i figured it out, they were static arrays, and weren't getting defined the way i expected, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do all that in the beginning. A multidimensional array cannot be jagged and automatically makes all inner arrays size 22 if you simply do

```
itemList = new int[10,22];
```

Further, you can initialize this like so:

```
itemList = new int[10,22] {
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22},
    {1, 3, 5, 7, 9 ...
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to use a jagged array and just need to change itemList initialiser to:

```
var itemList = new int[10][] { item0, item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9 };
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem

```
        var itemList = new int[][] {
        item0,
        item1,
        item2,
        item3,
        item4,
        item5,
        item6,
        };
```

But I recommend you to do it this way

```
        int[,] itemList = new int[,]
        {
            {1,2,3,4,5 },
            {1,2,3,4,5 },
            {1,2,3,4,5 },
        };
```